# async import with configurable path within npm library

Tags: angular, webpack, package, internationalization

I have a module that loads messages for angular i18n. The crucial part looks like this:

```
const lang = 'en';
const pathToLocales = 'path/to/locales';
const localeTranslationsModule = await import(`${pathToLocales}/messages.${lang}.json`);
// Load translations for the current locale at run-time
loadTranslations(localeTranslationsModule.default.translations);
```

This works perfectly fine as long as it is whithin the angular app. The path here would be something like `apps/my-app/i18n` where the message files are located.

Since I need this in several apps and I don't want the code to be in every single app I decided to extract this into a library `@my-org/i18n`.
Now when I am using the module from the `@my-org/i18n` and put the `path/to/locales` as parameter, it cannot find the path.

My guess is, that the path cannot be resolved relative to node_modules. But how would one then configure a path like that?

Comment: Could you please share the link to your package in npm?

Comment: Its in a private github npm registry, sorry. 
But you can find the base implementation of the i18n "module" here: https://github.com/whiteducksoftware/angular-i18n-demo/blob/main/runtime-translations/src/app/core/i18n/i18n.module.ts

Comment: Since you are using webpack dynamic expression syntax you must start the path with a static string and not a dynamic one, because webpack needs to know where to start https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import.

Comment: Great! so I will add it as an official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using webpack dynamic expression syntax you must start the path with a static string and not a dynamic one, because webpack needs to know where to start.
Something like:

```
import(`./locale/${language}.json`)
```

Checkout this [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)